# JavaScript regex captures only the last group occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse a documentation text, which is formatted like this :

```
className : String
A text
colHeaders : Boolean (default false) 
colHeaders : Array [A, B, C, ...] 
colHeaders : Function function(index) { return ... }
Another text
```

([Full documentation here](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options/91388ffd206060d7b227718ad3f98cda4f239f2d))

So every option in the documentation can be of multiple types, and I want to programatically recover them. I created a JavaScript regex :

```
^(\w+) : (\w+)[^\n]*(?:\n\1 : (\w+)[^\n]*)*
```

([Regex101 demo page here](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4kB6/2))

I successfully retrieve the first option type ('String' and 'Boolean' in the example above), but as far as the second part of the regex is concerned I can only retrieve the last group ('Function', where I would like both 'Array' and 'Function').

If I remove the '*' quantifier at the end of the regex, I only retrieve 'Array' (same thing if I add the non-greedy symbol '?' after it), but once again I would like both. Is there a way to do that in a JS regex ?

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/3a1jm your code seems to work ?

Comment: You use the wrong tool! Instead of trying parse a text version of the documentation, why you don't use the structured version of this same document (i.e. the html version)? You can more easily obtain what you want using the DOM.

Comment: @EmreAcar : No it doesn't. Hover the group and you'll see that the 2nd option type is not captured.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : I could indeed, but I like regex challenges :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is there a way to do that [access previous captures of a certain group] in a JS regex?"* - No.

You can however use two regexes - one that captures blocks:

```
/^(\w+) : .*(?:\n^\1.*)*/gm
```

and one that parses a block into lines:

```
/^\w+ : (\w+)\s*(.*)/gm
```

as in

```
var str = [
        'className : String',
        'A text',
        'colHeaders : Boolean (default false)',
        'colHeaders : Array [A, B, C, ...]',
        'colHeaders : Function function(index) { return ... }',
        'Another text'
    ].join("\n"),
    reBlock = /^(\w+) : .*(?:\n^\1.*)*/gm,
    reLine = /^\w+ : (\w+)\s*(.*)/gm,
    block, line;

while (block = reBlock.exec(str)) {
    console.log(block[1]);
    while (line = reLine.exec(block[0])) {
        console.log(" - ", line[1], line[2]);
    }
}
```

prints

```
 className
  -  String 
 colHeaders
  -  Boolean (default false)
  -  Array [A, B, C, ...]
  -  Function function(index) { return ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I considered the possibility of using one regex for the option name and another for the option type, but using only one regex seems shorter. So it probably means that I don't understand the way capturing works.  What does my regex mean then ?

Comment: If a capturing group matches multiple times (because it has a quantifier), only the *last* match value is remembered by the JavaScript regex engine. This is a limitation most regex engines have (the engine in .NET is an exception from the rule). You simply cannot do what you want in one expression in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then I guess your two-part regex proposal is the best I can get

Comment: In JavaScript and most other regex dialects, yes.